# Find the derivative of $z^{\sin z}$ at $z = i$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

So I have encountered a question in which we have to evaluate the derivative of $$z^{\sin z}$$ at $z = i$ using the principal branch of the complex power that is using the principal branch of log (Log).
I have tried expanding the complex power using the formula $$z^{\sin z}=e^{(\sin z)\operatorname{Log}(z)}$$ To obtain $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ but this yields a lengthy-expression which isn't very easy to differentiate. Is there a way to differentiate this easily or do we have to differentiate the expanded complex power and then substitute z = i?

Comment: Are you familiar with the results which show that all of the "usual" differentiation rules work over the complex numbers?  e.g. the chain rule, the product rule, &c?  It seems that you are making things far more difficult than they need to be by looking to the real and imaginary parts of the derivative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(z^{sinz})' = (e^{sinz \cdot lnz})' = (cosz \cdot lnz + sinz \cdot 1/z)\cdot e^{sinz \cdot ln z} = (cosz \cdot lnz + sinz \cdot 1/z) z^{sinz}$$

Since $ \sin(ix) = i \sinh(x) $ and $ \cos(ix) = cosh(x) $:

$$(z^{sinz})'|_{z=1} = (\cosh(1) \cdot (0+ i (\pi / 2+2k\pi)) + i \sinh(1) \cdot 1/i) \cdot i^{i \sinh(1) }$$

Comment: the 2kπ will not be needed since in the question only the principal branch of the log is considered right?

Comment: You do need it, because the identities of real exponential and logarithmic functions, in order to extrapolate them to the complex world, you have to use the general version of logarithm. In other words, if you take the main branch you will only get the **principal value** of z^sinz.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to use logarithms and implicit differentiation.

$$u := z^{\sin z}$$
$$\log u = \sin z \log z$$
$$\frac{d}{dz} \log u = \frac{d}{dz}(\sin z \log z)$$
$$\frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{dz} = (\log z)(\frac{d}{dz}\sin z) + (\sin z)(\frac{d}{dz} \log z)$$
$$\frac{1}{z^{\sin z}} \frac{du}{dz} = (\log z)(\cos z) + (\sin z)(\frac{1}{z})$$
$$\frac{du}{dz} = \frac{z^{\sin z}(z(\log z)(\cos z) + \sin z)}{z}$$

Now, what do you get when you plug in $z = i$?  The identity $e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i\sin{x}$ may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can show with logarithmic differentiation that
$$f(z)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}(z^{\sin z})=z^{-1+\sin z}(\sin z+z\log z\cos z)$$

So
$$f(\mathrm i)=\mathrm i^{-1+\sin \mathrm i}(\sin \mathrm i+\mathrm i\log \mathrm i\cos \mathrm i)$$

We can compute this. See,
$$\sin(z)=\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm iz}-\mathrm e^{-\mathrm iz}}{2\mathrm i} \\ \sin(\mathrm i)=\frac{1}{2\mathrm i}(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)$$
Similarly $\cos(\mathrm i)=\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm e^{-1}+\mathrm e)$.

Recall also that
$$\log z=\log|z|+\mathrm i\operatorname{arg}z$$
So
$$\log \mathrm i=\log|\mathrm i|+\mathrm i\operatorname{arg}\mathrm i=\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm i$$
Finally,
$$\mathrm i^s=\exp(s\log\mathrm i)=\exp\left(s~\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm i\right)$$
So
$$\mathrm i^{-1+\sin \mathrm i}=\exp\left((-1+\sin \mathrm i)~\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm i\right) \\ =\exp\left(\left(-1+\frac{1}{2\mathrm i}(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)\right)~\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm i\right) \\ =\exp\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm i+\frac{\pi}{4}(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)\right) \\ =\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\pi/2}\mathrm e^{\pi(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)/4}$$

Putting it all together,
$$f(\mathrm i)=\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\pi/2}\mathrm e^{\pi(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)/4}~\left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm i}(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)+\mathrm i~\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm i~\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm e^{-1}+\mathrm e)\right) $$
Simplifying and using $\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\pi/2}=-\mathrm i$,
$$f(\mathrm i)=-\mathrm i~\mathrm e^{\pi(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)/4}\left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm i}(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)-\frac{\pi}{4}(\mathrm e^{-1}+\mathrm e)\right) \\ =\mathrm e^{\pi(\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e)/4}\left(\frac{\mathrm i\pi}{4}(\mathrm e^{-1}+\mathrm e)+\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm e-\mathrm e^{-1})\right)$$

This has an approximate numerical value of
$$0.185526+0.382649~\mathrm i$$

As confirmed by Mathematica:

[image: mathematica output]